# Birthday calculator format exception errors

Tags: java

I now there are a few threads on this already.  This one in particular keeps coming up in my searches:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219732/how-would-i-subtract-two-dates-mm-dd-yyyy

However it just does not seem to do what I want or it could just be i'm not understanding the concepts in the thread.  Basically I just want to take the user input (eg. 12 17 1980) and subtract it from the current date to get the persons actual age.  What I've read from the previous threads and other just seems so complicated just to do this simple calculation. As of right now the program compiles but after I input a date I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12 13 1981"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at bdayCalc.Class2.setAge(Class2.java:17)
at bdayCalc.Class1.main(Class1.java:20)
```

Here is what I have in my program so far:

```
package bdayCalc;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Class1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Class2 object2 = new Class2();

    System.out.print("What is your name? : ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    object2.setName(name);
    object2.message();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please enter your birthday : ");
    String userInput = input.nextLine();
    object2.setAge(userInput);
    object2.finalMessage();
  }
}

package bdayCalc;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Class2 {
int year = Calendar.DATE;
private String fullName;

public void setName(String name) {
    fullName = name;
}

private int bDay;
public void setAge(String userInput) {
    bDay = Integer.parseInt(userInput) - year;
}

/*private int year() {
    return 0;
}*/

public String getName() {
    return fullName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return bDay;
}

public void message() {
    System.out.printf("Hello %s ", getName());
}

public void finalMessage() {
    System.out.printf(getName() + " You were born in " + bDay);
}

}
```

Comment: The`String` `"12 13 1981"` is not a representation of an `int` because of the whitespace. Hence, it will throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: I was thinking of doing that but i'm just stuck on the idea of subtracting the input from the current time.  There has to be a simple way of  doing this.

Comment: I have compiled one example. Please check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have quickly compiled one simple example which will work for you. It uses Java 8 `Date` API:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your birthday (YYYY-MM-DD) format: ");
        String userInput = input.nextLine();
        String[] splitValues = userInput.split("-");
        if(splitValues.length == 3) {
            int year = Integer.parseInt(splitValues[0]);
            int mon = Integer.parseInt(splitValues[1]);
            int day = Integer.parseInt(splitValues[2]);

            LocalDate birthdate = LocalDate.of(year, mon, day);
            LocalDate now =LocalDate.now();
            long age = Period.between(birthdate, now).getYears();
            System.out.println(age);
        }
    }
```

And here is the output:

`Please enter your birthday : 1981-10-22
33`

Comment: wow you guys make programming seem so easy.  I'm gonna use your answer akhil.  However I'm gonna have to read it a bunch of times just to make sure it sinks it.  Mainly I want to fully understand the last 6 lines.  I think I get it.  Thanks man.

Comment: Glad to help you Narain :) One suggestion use birthday format as `YYYY-DD-MM` and not as `YYYY DD MM`. I will format the code now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter your birthday as mm/dd/yyyy: ");
    while (true) {
        String userInput = input.nextLine();
        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy").parse(userInput);
            long ageInDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(new Date().getTime() - date.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            int age = (int) ageInDays / 365;
            System.out.println(age);
            break;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valide date");
        }
    }
}
```